# AJAX Return Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to POST a variable through a select box, which will submit the data through AJAX and then I need to be able to use that variable on the original page, which updates the SQL queries.

Here is the code I have got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectCategory() {

    document.getElementById('categoryText').addEventListener("change", function() {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/category.php?category3="
            +document.getElementById("categoryText").value, false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    });

}
</script>
```

and the AJAX (which I'm struggling with)

```
<?php 

    /*Retrieving the Value from the select box */
    $categoryFilter = $_GET['category3']; 

?>
```

Comment: can you provide the html code ?

Comment: remove `null` from `xmlhttp.send(null);`

Comment: which part of the code do you have trouble with? server or client?

Comment: I just need the current value for $categoryFilter to change once changed in the select box

Comment: @GiamPy Its not changing the categoryFilter php vairiable, which is needed to filter the SQL on the page

Comment: @Frog82 have you tried using `POST` instead? Seems rather simple considering you're passing a variable. Unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "select box" do you mean a select menu - ie: dropdown? If that is the case then generally you access the value of the selected element like this:-

```
var oSel=document.getElementById("categoryText");
var value=oSel.options[ oSel.options.selectedIndex ].value

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectCategory() {
            var oSel=document.getElementById('categoryText')
            oSel.addEventListener("change", function() {
                var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open( "GET", "/category.php?category3="+this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ].value, false );
                xmlhttp.send(null);
            }.bind( oSel ) );
        }
        selectCategory.call( this );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
data=[];
data.push({name: 'category3', value: checked/unchecked });
$('.submit').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'your php page url',
  data: formData,
  success:function(data){
    // successful request; do something with the data
    alert(data);
  },
  error:function(){
     // failed request; give feedback to user
    alert("error");
  }
    });

});
```

and in PHP:

```
$categoryFilter = $POST['category3'];
```